# How to run a node.js app on Azure app service with a windows host

Tags: node.js, azure

Trying to use Azure App Services.
From within Code I can create a new app service and deploy a html/js/css app choosing a windows host.
From within Code I can create a new app service and deploy a node.js app choosing a Linux host.

But I can't figure out how to create a new app service and deploy a node.js app choosing a windows host.  I am fairly sure it should work.  It gives no error when I deploy it, if I go to the resulting web page it gives me the "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." message.  I know about setting port 443.

You might ask, why do this?  Because I am a teacher, and Azure for students allows multiple app service instances using a windows host but only 1 on a Linux host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring solution mentioned here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/issues/9

1. Create a web.config file at the root of the app directory.
2. Add the following code to web.config:

   ```
   <!-- indicates that the index.js file is a node.js application 
   to be handled by the iisnode module -->

   <handlers>
     <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
   </handlers>

   <!-- adds index.js to the default document list to allow 
   URLs that only specify the application root location, 
   e.g. http://mysite.antarescloud.com/ -->

   <defaultDocument enabled="true">
     <files>
       <add value="index.js" />
     </files>
   </defaultDocument>
   ```

You probably need change "index.js" to what initial js file name in your project.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much.  That change enabled the code to deploy, and the windows host is serving the index.js (in my case, app.js).  However, deploying the identical app to Linux host and Windows hosts, my call back for data from client to server using AJAX works on the Linux host, but not on the Windows host. I'll post another question for that problem.   thanks much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268722/azure-app-service-ajax-not-working-from-windows-host-but-does-work-from-linux-h